# Matching a specific text with grepl but not the sub-strings of that text

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to match a specific text using `grepl()` whilst ensuring no shorter sub-strings return a match as well.

For example, I want `grepl('liverpool', 'club_futbol_liverpool_fc')` to return `TRUE`, yet I don't want `grepl('pool', 'club_futbol_liverpool_fc')` to return `TRUE`. I can't use `^` and `$` in this case, because there are characters before and after the text I want to match. Writing `grepl('.*^liverpool$.*', 'club_futbol_liverpool_fc')` doesn't help either, which I only just realised is the same as using only `^` and `$`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I should add that the end goal is to use this `grepl()` function in a for loop to match observations in a data frame. Unfortunately, `liverpool` won't always be surrounded by underscores, although I believe that there will always be at least one underscore, either before or after `liverpool`.

Comment: Use `grepl('(?:\b|_)pool(?:\b|_)', 'club_futbol_liverpool_fc')`

Comment: thanks for answering! I should add that the end goal is to use this grepl() function in a for loop to match observations in a data frame. Unfortunately, _liverpool_ won't always be surrounded by underscores, although I believe that there will always be at least one underscore, either before or after 'liverpool'.

Comment: What do you mean? The regex above matches a whole word `pool`, even inside underscores, but does not require underscores. Post your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
grepl('(?:\b|_)pool(?:\b|_)', x)
grepl('(?<![^\\W_])pool(?![^\\W_])', x, perl = TRUE)
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/HNOYnn/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/HNOYnn/2).

The patterns above mean

- `(?:\b|_)` - word boundary or a `_` char that is consumed
- `(?<![^\W_])` - a location in the string that is not immediately preceded with a letter or digit (`[^\W_]` matches any char other than a non-word char and an underscore, that is, that matches any word char but an underscore, effectively, a letter or a digit)
- `pool` - a word
- `(?![^\W_])` - a location in the string that is not immediately followed with a letter or digit.

The lookarounds, `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are non-consuming patterns and the default TRE regex library does not support them, so you need to use `perl=TRUE` to parse the expressions with the PCRE regex library.